# passing fields of an array of collections through functions in python

Tags: python

is there a way of passing a field of an array of collections into a function so that it can still be used to access a element in the collection in python?. i am attempting to search through an array of collections to locate a particular item by comparing it with an identifier. this identifier and field being compared will change as the function is called in different stages of the program. is there a way of passing up the field to the function, to access the required element for comparison? 
this is the code that i have tried thus far:
[code ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmvsi.png)

Comment: "a field of an array of collections" Phew, could you please [edit] your question and include an example for what you try to do?

Comment: Hint: Since you put code into graphic files, maybe this will help: https://xkcd.com/1685/

Comment: Although I dont entirely understand what you want, you are probably looking for [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `M_work` is a list. Lists are accessed using an index and this syntax: `myList[index]`. So that would translate to `M_work[place]` in your case. Then you say that `M_work` stores objects which have fields, and you want to access one of these fields by name. To do that, use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) like this: `getattr(M_work[place], field)`. You can compare the return value to `identifier`.

Other mistakes in the code you show:

- `place` is misspelled `pace` at one point.
- `True` is misspelled `true` at one point.
- The body of your loop always returns at the first iteration: there is a `return` in both the `if found == True` and `else` branches. I don't think this is what you want.

You could improve your code by:

- noticing that `if found == True` is equivalent to `if found`.
- finding how you don't actually need the `found` variable.
- looking at [Python's `for...in` loop](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops).

Comment: thank you so much!!!, that work so well and your suggestions allowed me to simplify my code so much, your amassing!  thank you.